# Convert Newtosoft JObject directly to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

Try to convert `JObject` to `BsonDocument` using this example https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteJTokenToBson.htm (`BsonWriter` obsolete, so I use `BsonDataWriter`)

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse("{\"name\":\"value\"}");

using var writer = new BsonDataWriter(new MemoryStream());
jObject.WriteTo(writer);

var bsonData = writer.ToBsonDocument();

Console.WriteLine(bsonData.ToJson());
```

output:

```
{ "CloseOutput" : true, "AutoCompleteOnClose" : true, "Formatting" : 0, "DateFormatHandling" : 0, "DateTimeZoneHandling" : 3, "StringEscapeHandling" : 0, "FloatFormatHandling" : 0, "DateFormatString" : null
, "Culture" : { "Name" : "", "UseUserOverride" : false }, "DateTimeKindHandling" : 1 }
```

Expected output is:

```
{"name": "value"}
```

How can I fix it?

**UPD**: I have a JObject, and I want to convert it directly to BSONDocument, avoid serialization to string and string parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a `JObject` to a BSON stream using Newtonsoft's [`BsonDataWriter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson/BsonDataWriter.cs) like so:

```
var json = "{\"name\":\"value\"}";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

using var stream = new MemoryStream(); // Or open a FileStream if you prefer
using (var writer = new BsonDataWriter(stream) { CloseOutput = false })
{
    jObject.WriteTo(writer);
}
// Reset the stream position to 0 if you are going to immediately re-read it.
stream.Position = 0;
```

Then, you can parse the written stream with the MongoDB .NET Driver like so:

```
// Parse the BSON using the MongoDB driver
BsonDocument bsonData;
using (var reader = new BsonBinaryReader(stream))
{
    var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(reader);
    bsonData = BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(context);            
}
```

And check the validity of the created document like so:

```
// Verify that the BsonDocument is semantically identical to the original JSON.
// Write it to JSON using the MongoDB driver
var newJson = bsonData.ToJson();

Console.WriteLine(newJson); // Prints { "name" : "value" }

// And assert that the old and new JSON are semantically identical
Assert.IsTrue(JToken.DeepEquals(JToken.Parse(json), JToken.Parse(newJson))); // Passes
```

Notes:

- When you do `var bsonData = writer.ToBsonDocument();` you are actually *serializing Newtonsoft's `BsonDataWriter` using the MongoDB extension method [`BsonExtensionMethods.ToBsonDocument()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonExtensionMethods_ToBsonDocument__1.htm)*, which explains the strange contents of the `bsonData` document in your test code.

  Instead, the serialized BSON can be obtained from the stream to which it was just written.
- If you are going to immediately re-read the stream, you can keep it open by setting [`JsonWriter.CloseOutput = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_CloseOutput.htm).  Set the stream position to `0` after writing.
- While your approach avoids the overhead of serializing and parsing a JSON string, you are still serializing and deserializing a BSON binary stream.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4wFkBM).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the json string already, you can simply create a bson document out of it

```
var document= BsonDocument.Parse("{\"name\":\"value\"}");
```

If you strictly have a JObject, you can Serialize the JObject and then parse the result to a BSONDocument

```
var document = BsonDocument.Parse(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject));
```

Comment: I have a JObject, and I want to convert it directly to BSONDocument (avoid serialization to string and string parsing)

Answer (score 1):

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104268/7818969) avoids serialization to a string but serializes to binary instead just to then deserialize it right after.
The following maps `JObject` do `BsonDocument` by straightforward traversal:

```cs
public static BsonDocument ToBsonDocument(this JObject o) =>
    new(o.Properties().Select(p => new BsonElement(p.Name, p.Value.ToBsonValue())));

public static BsonValue ToBsonValue(this JToken t) =>
    t switch
    {
        JObject o => o.ToBsonDocument(),
        JArray a => new BsonArray(a.Select(ToBsonValue)),
        JValue v => BsonValue.Create(v.Value),
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"ToBsonValue: {t}")
    };
```