# How to convert JsonElement to BsonDocument efficiently?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, bson, system.text.json

In my asp net core 6 application I need to convert `JsonElement` object to `BsonDocument`. Surely I can serialize `JsonElement` to a string and then do `BsonDocument.Parse` but I believe there must be faster and more efficient way to do it. Any ideas?

There is `BsonDocument.Create` method which creates a bson document from `object` instance. But I couldn't find a way to convert `JsonElement` to object. Even if I do `myJsonElment.Deserialize<object>()` or `myJsonElment.Deserialize<dynamic>()`, an output still has `JsonElement` real-time type.

Comment: Does this one help?https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788508/20240963

Comment: @QiangFu It's reverse situation. I already can convert `BsonDocument` to `JsonElement`. But I need to do it another way around

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175724) by [peebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818969/peebo) to *[Convert Newtosoft JObject directly to BsonDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62080252/3744182)* to convert directly from [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement) to [`BsonDocument`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/data-formats/bson/#std-label-csharp-bson-api) as follows:

```
public static class BsonExtensions
{
    // Rewritten from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175724 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818969/peebo
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080252/convert-newtosoft-jobject-directly-to-bsondocument
    public static BsonDocument ToBsonDocument(this JsonElement e, bool writeRootArrayAsDocument = false, bool tryParseDateTimes = false) =>
        e.ValueKind switch
        {
            JsonValueKind.Object => 
                new(e.EnumerateObject().Select(p => new BsonElement(p.Name, p.Value.ToBsonValue(tryParseDateTimes)))),
            // Newtonsoft converts arrays to documents by using the index as a key, so optionally do the same thing.
            JsonValueKind.Array when writeRootArrayAsDocument => 
                new(e.EnumerateArray().Select((v, i)  => new BsonElement(i.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), v.ToBsonValue(tryParseDateTimes)))),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"ToBsonDocument: {e}"),
        };

    public static BsonValue ToBsonValue(this JsonElement e, bool tryParseDateTimes = false) =>
        e.ValueKind switch
        {
            // TODO: determine whether you want strings that look like dates & times to be serialized as DateTime, DateTimeOffset, or just strings.
            JsonValueKind.String when tryParseDateTimes && e.TryGetDateTime(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
            JsonValueKind.String => BsonValue.Create(e.GetString()),
            // TODO: decide whether to convert to Int64 unconditionally, or only when the value is larger than Int32
            JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetInt32(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
            JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetInt64(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
            // TODO: decide whether to convert floating values to decimal by default.  Decimal has more precision but a smaller range.
            //JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetDecimal(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
            JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetDouble(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
            JsonValueKind.Null => BsonValue.Create(null),
            JsonValueKind.True => BsonValue.Create(true),
            JsonValueKind.False => BsonValue.Create(false),
            JsonValueKind.Array => new BsonArray(e.EnumerateArray().Select(v => v.ToBsonValue(tryParseDateTimes))),
            JsonValueKind.Object => e.ToBsonDocument(false, tryParseDateTimes),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"ToBsonValue: {e}"),
    };
}
```

And now you could do:

```
using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json); // JsonDocument is disposable, and must be disposed to free up pooled memory.
var bsonDoc = jsonDoc.RootElement.ToBsonDocument(true);
```

Notes:

- JSON has no official format for dates and times, but if you want to serialize strings that can be parsed as `DateTime` objects to BSON as such, pass `tryParseDateTimes : true`.
- A `BsonDocument` is always a collection of key/value pairs, and so the root `JsonElement` must be an object, not an array.  Newtonsoft's `BsonWriter` removes this restriction by serializing arrays as key/value pairs where the key is the string representation of the index.  If you want to preserve this behavior, pass `writeRootArrayAsDocument : true`.
- No attempt is made to convert MongoDB's [extended JSON format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/) to BSON.  If you need this, it might be better just to parse the original JSON string via `BsonDocument.Parse(element.GetRawText())`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IFr0Mu).