# Dotnet API Error Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Dotnet Core API and MongoDB as my database.
I am trying to create a simple CURD operation for one collection.
The Get method for API is working properly but I am getting error for Post call. I tried several options available but nothing seems to be working.

The error is below

> *MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: An error occurred while serializing the Metadata property of class Datasparkx_Model.AdminForm.AdminFormModel: Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.*

ModelClass =>

```
public class MyModel
{
  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public string? Id { get; set; }
  
  public Object[] Testdata { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Call =>

```
[HttpPost(Name = "AddData")]
public async Task<bool> Post(MyModel document)
{
    await _myCollection.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```

Javascript call

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "testData": [
    {
      "data1": "name",
      "data2": "textfield",
      "data3": true
    },
    {
      "data1": "email",
      "data3": "email",
      "data4": true
    },
    {
      "randomData": "address",
      "newData": false,
      "anyData": "textarea"
    }
  ]
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://localhost:7051/AddData", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The parameters are passed properly as expected at Controller level but it doesn't add any data in my database and throws the above error.

Can someone please guide me as I am new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you declare the `Testdata` as `Object[]` type:

```cs
public Object[] Testdata { get; set; }
```

When the `JsonSerializer` deserializes the request data, the object in the `Testdata` will be defined as `JsonElement` by default. And MongoDB .NET Driver / `BsonSerializer` does not support (de)serializing the `JsonElement`.

Either:

1. Have the additional implementation to convert `JsonElement` to `BsonElement` as [@dbc's answer on How to convert JsonElement to BsonDocument efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76491721/8017690)
2. Serialize the `document` via `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` and deserialize with `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer`.

Note that when you using this approach, you should exclude deserializing `Id` to prevent the error that `Id` is not found in the model class. Or you may apply the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute to the `MyModel` class.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

string serializedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(document, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
});

document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(json);
await _collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

> Demo

[image]