# Dotnet API Error indicating: The System.Text.Json.JsonElement type isn't configured for serialization within this ObjectSerializer instance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, .net-6.0

I have dynamic models structured in columns and content within Dotnet API. The error indicates that the "System.Text.Json.JsonElement" type isn't configured for serialization in this ObjectSerializer instance. Your assistance in resolving this matter is greatly appreciated.

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: An error occurred while serializing the content property of class pm_management.API.Domain.Models.ProjectIdentification: Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.
 ---> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Type System.Text.Json.JsonElement is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer.
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.SerializeDiscriminatedValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value, Type actualType)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, TValue value)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TValue value)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, Object value)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeMember(BsonSerializationContext context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
```

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace pm_management.API.Domain.Models
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class ProjectIdentification
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public Object[] content { get; set; }

        public Object[] columns { get; set; }

        public Theme theme { get; set; }
        public void SetContentAndColumns(string contentJson, string columnsJson)
        {
            content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Object[]>(contentJson);
            columns = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Object[]>(columnsJson);
        }

    }
    public static class BsonExtensions
    {
        // Rewritten from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175724 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818969/peebo
        // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080252/convert-newtosoft-jobject-directly-to-bsondocument
        public static BsonDocument ToBsonDocument(this JsonElement e, bool writeRootArrayAsDocument = false, bool tryParseDateTimes = false) =>
            e.ValueKind switch
            {
                JsonValueKind.Object =>
                    new(e.EnumerateObject().Select(p => new BsonElement(p.Name, p.Value.ToBsonValue(tryParseDateTimes)))),
                // Newtonsoft converts arrays to documents by using the index as a key, so optionally do the same thing.
                JsonValueKind.Array when writeRootArrayAsDocument =>
                    new(e.EnumerateArray().Select((v, i) => new BsonElement(i.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), v.ToBsonValue(tryParseDateTimes)))),
                _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"ToBsonDocument: {e}"),
            };

        public static BsonValue ToBsonValue(this JsonElement e, bool tryParseDateTimes = false) =>
            e.ValueKind switch
            {
                // TODO: determine whether you want strings that look like dates & times to be serialized as DateTime, DateTimeOffset, or just strings.
                JsonValueKind.String when tryParseDateTimes && e.TryGetDateTime(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
                JsonValueKind.String => BsonValue.Create(e.GetString()),
                // TODO: decide whether to convert to Int64 unconditionally, or only when the value is larger than Int32
                JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetInt32(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
                JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetInt64(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
                // TODO: decide whether to convert floating values to decimal by default.  Decimal has more precision but a smaller range.
                //JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetDecimal(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
                JsonValueKind.Number when e.TryGetDouble(out var v) => BsonValue.Create(v),
                JsonValueKind.Null => BsonValue.Create(null),
                JsonValueKind.True => BsonValue.Create(true),
                JsonValueKind.False => BsonValue.Create(false),
                JsonValueKind.Array => new BsonArray(e.EnumerateArray().Select(v => v.ToBsonValue(tryParseDateTimes))),
                JsonValueKind.Object => e.ToBsonDocument(false, tryParseDateTimes),
                _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"ToBsonValue: {e}"),
            };
    }

}
```

```
  private readonly IMongoCollection<ProjectIdentification> _collection;

  public ProjectIdentificationRepository(IOptions<MongoDbSettings> mongoDbSettings)
  {
      var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
          mongoDbSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

      var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
          mongoDbSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

      _collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<ProjectIdentification>("Project");
  }

  public async Task AddProject(ProjectIdentification project)
  {
      string serializedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(project, new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
          DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
      });

      ProjectIdentification deserializedProject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProjectIdentification>(serializedJson);

      await _collection.InsertOneAsync(deserializedProject);
  }



  public async Task<ProjectIdentification> GetProjectById(string id)
  {
      var filter = Builders<ProjectIdentification>.Filter.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
      var result = await _collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

      if (result != null)
      {
          return result;
      }

      return null;
  }
```

I have dynamic models structured in columns and content within Dotnet API

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "65edc0c6482da8bd8368fbbf" },
  "Id": "65edc0c6482da8bd8368fbbe",
  "content": [
    {
      "id": "z5LllRt-NoiGkoisa_2tN",
      "type": "image",
      "data": {
        "style": "circle",
        "image": "/images/profile.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "QfAFa0golVKIImL764OCO",
      "type": "text",
      "data": {
        "headline": "Horst Karacho",
        "description": "My name is Horst :)",
        "rank":"test",
        "anotherfield":"tesst"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "j3ofcLmYExoG0AS_yoRq0",
      "type": "text",
      "data": {
        "headline": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna...",
        "details": {
          "author": "Unknown",
          "publishedDate": "2023-01-15",
          "wordCount": 245
        }
      }
    },
    
  ],
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": "mOceUBR-oB5xEzfstycFh",
      "content": [
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN0",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN1",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN11",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN12",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN3",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN4",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN5",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN6",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN7",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN8",
        "qkx4WlS5XkUZcfTpy9rN9"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "theme": {
    "HighlightColor": "#3f51b5",
    "HeadlineColor": "#95A5A6",
    "HeadlineFontType": "Roboto",
    "HeadlineFontSize": "1.8em",
    "HeadlineFontWeight": "600",
    "HeadlineBorderType": "dashed",
    "TextColor": "#333",
    "TextFontType": "Source Sans Pro",
    "TextFontSize": "1em",
    "TextFontWeight": "200"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77484005/dotnet-api-error-type-system-text-json-jsonelement-is-not-configured-as-a-type-t

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I've already checked into that before reaching out for help